# How to check what software has been used to generate bam file?

Tags: sam, ngs, read-mapping

I have several bam files from unknown origin. I'd like to know what software was used to obtain those bam files, e.g. `bwa-mem`. Is it possible to somehow check it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're lucky the information is stored in the BAM header in the lines starting with `@PG` which stores the command lines run on the BAM, use `samtools view -H your.bam` to display the header.

Comment: Indeed, there was the full command line, thanks!